# XCode + cmake ignoring updates to the current build

Tags: xcode, cmake

I'm trying to cross-compile a c++/Objective-C project using Xcode. The first time I build it the application is build just fine and runs correctly. The problem is that after that, any modification to the code simply doesn't refer to the application. I can see the code compiling, and can confirm that the source file was built but this doesn't change the application at all!

I've tried to remove the built libraries, the generated application and even cleaning the project seems to not change the outputted application. It seems that the new lib is being generated on another folder and the compiler is not finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found that removing the generated binary inside the .app and building again forces the re-linkage of everything. Annoying but at least I don't have to do a full clean+rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

There's something weird about it indeed. For me, removing related .o file, linked app binary and also entire .dSYM folder helped.

Comment: The problem is probably tied to issue #12451, see [here](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12451).